# Group By Nullable Column In Teradata

Tags: group-by, teradata

What happens when I group by a column in Teradata which is nullable ? Are those records which have the corresponding field's value AS NULL get eliminated ? 
Please Explain with an example !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every DBMS treats NULLs in the GROUP BY columns like any other value and puts them into one group. Eliminated are NULLs in the aggregated columns.

Why don't you simply test it?